# Php Register Email Verification

Tags: php, email, verification

I've put together a registration form for my website which will use an email verification. I would like to select a default mailbox to send outgoing emails. How do i specify which mail box on my webhosting the outgoing email will be sent from?

```
if($result2){
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Immo Registration Confirmation - $username";
    $header = "Immo: Confirmation from Immo";
    $message = "Thank you for registering at Immo Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. <br>";
    $message .= "http://www.test.com/confirm.php?passkey=$confirmcode";

    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    if($sentmail)
    {
    echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
    }
}
```

The email system is working, I have tested it however the email address that it's coming from is random spam and i would like to assign a certain mailbox  for registration. How can this be achieved?

Comment: So you're asking if you can control where the email gets delivered on the user's personal email?

Comment: $header .= 'From: from@mail.com \r\n';

Comment: You should probably switch to a library like phpmailer or swift so that you can easily use authentication and connect to a specific account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the sender email by adding this to your $header variable.

```
$header .= 'From: from@mail.com \r\n';
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! Any reason why it's going straight to my junk folder?

Comment: You need to make sure the email is coming from the same domain as the sender. there is also many other factors and may be worth doing further research.

Comment: `\r\n` doesn't get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) specifically states: *"Make sure you enclose \r\n in double quotes (not single quotes!) so that PHP can translate that into the correct linefeed code"*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the 'From' header correctly. something like below taken from the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```